# libx11 can't take screenshot on Fedora OS C

Tags: c, linux, x11, cairo

I am not a specialist in C programming and Linux OS development, but I have a task about making screenshots on Ubuntu and Fedora OS. After searching on the internet I found a lot of topics and questions about how to do it using C language and libX11. Finally, I combined all I could find in one method which captures the screenshot and saves to .png file.
I have two virtual machines installed - one is Ubuntu 18.04, the second is Fedora 30. When I run my code on Ubuntu - it works perfectly, when I run it on Fedora - I have a screenshot file with black content.
My code is:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XShm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <cairo.h>
#include <cairo-xlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int get_shift (int mask) {
        int shift = 0;
        while (mask) {
            if (mask & 1) break;
            shift++;
            mask >>=1;
        }
        return shift;
    }

   void takeScreenshot() {
    Display *d;
    int s;
    XImage *image;
    XShmSegmentInfo shminfo;
    d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    s = DefaultScreen(d);
    unsigned int width = DisplayWidth(d,s);
    unsigned int height = DisplayHeight(d,s);


    image = XShmCreateImage(d, 
        DefaultVisual(d,s), // Use a correct visual. Omitted for brevity     
        24,   // Determine correct depth from the visual. Omitted for brevity
        ZPixmap, NULL, &shminfo, width, height); 

    shminfo.shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,
        image->bytes_per_line * image->height,
        IPC_CREAT|0777);

    shminfo.shmaddr = image->data = shmat(shminfo.shmid, 0, 0);
    shminfo.readOnly = False;

    XShmAttach(d, &shminfo);

    XShmGetImage(d,
        RootWindow(d,s),
        image,
        0,
        0,
        AllPlanes);


    cairo_surface_t *surface;
    int stride;

    stride = cairo_format_stride_for_width(CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, width);
    unsigned char *data = malloc(stride * height);

    int redShift = get_shift(image->red_mask);
    int greenShift = get_shift(image->green_mask);
    int blueShift = get_shift(image->blue_mask);

    printf("r_shift: %d; g_shift: %d; b_shift: %d\n",redShift, greenShift, blueShift);
    printf("byte order: %d\n", image->byte_order);
    printf("bytes per line: %d\n", image->bytes_per_line);
    printf("bites per pixel: %d\n", image->bits_per_pixel);
    printf("r_mask: %lu; g_mask: %lu; b_mask: %lu\n", image->red_mask, image->green_mask, image->blue_mask);
    printf("bitmap_bit_order: %d  bitmap_pad: %d format: %d xoffset: %d\n", image->bitmap_bit_order, image->bitmap_pad, image->format, image->xoffset);

    int x, y;
     for (y = 0; y < height; ++y){
        for (x = 0; x < width; ++x) {

            unsigned long pixel = XGetPixel(image, x, y);

            unsigned char red = (image->red_mask & pixel)>>redShift;
            unsigned char green = (image->green_mask & pixel)>>greenShift;
            unsigned char blue = (image->blue_mask & pixel)>>blueShift;

            data[y * stride + x * 4 + 0] = blue;
            data[y * stride + x * 4 + 1] = green;
            data[y * stride + x * 4 + 2] = red;   
        }
    }

    surface = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data(
            data,
            CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24,
            width, height,
            stride);

    cairo_status_t surfaceStatus = cairo_surface_status(surface);

   const char *r = cairo_status_to_string (surfaceStatus);
   printf("%s\n", &r[0]);

    int writepngRes = cairo_surface_write_to_png(
                surface,
                "test.png");

    printf("surf status: %d; write result: %d\n", surfaceStatus, writepngRes);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
}


    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        takeScreenshot();
        return 0;
    }
```

And I build this code using following command:
`gcc code.c -o code.so -lXss -lX11 -lXext -fPIC -I/usr/include/cairo -lcairo`


The setup is exactly the same on both machines, what I have checked is that bit mask, byte order and bytes per pixel are equal for both systems. I am asking for suggestions about how to find a bug reason, maybe advice which thing to debug. Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
When I run this code on both platforms I see exactly the same output:

```
r_shift: 16; g_shift: 8; b_shift: 0
byte order: 0
bytes per line: 5464
bites per pixel: 32
r_mask: 16711680; g_mask: 65280; b_mask: 255
bitmap_bit_order: 0  bitmap_pad: 32 format: 2 xoffset: 0
no error has occurred
surf status: 0; write result: 0
```

Comment: Well, currently you are not checking the return codes from `cairo_surface_write_to_png` and `cairo_image_surface_create_for_data` - maybe start by printing them and compare them on both systems. Also you can use `cairo_surface_status ` on the returned surface from `cairo_image_surface_create_for_data` to see if the surface is ok. If everything still works the same on both machines it could be a cairo issue, where maybe it is compiled without png support? Why are you explicitly including png and linking against `libpng16` if you do not use that library in your code?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to remove this link since I tested a lot of approaches while developed. Okay, I will compare these return codes and post a result here. Thanks

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis, I made an update to the topic, the result is the same for both systems

Comment: Can you dump the raw rgb values to a file and compare them? To understand if the data is already black, or is there an issue with the actual saving to png?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis I made a dump to text file in hex format: this is file content on Ubuntu `"4D5558004D555800"`, and this is on Fedora `"0000000000000000"`. Looks like there  is problem in `XShmCreateImage`, right?

Comment: Yes, maybe you must actually query the bit depth from somewhere instead of the hardcoded 24?

Comment: You could actually run `xquery -c` on both systems and check what values are returned. They will most likely differ - on Ubuntu it should be 24, on Fedora - smth else :D

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis, I couldn't run xquery -c, but I found another way to get it: `xwininfo -root | grep Depth:` but result is 24 on both systems :(

Comment: Also I checked result codes of every operation and all of them seems to be ok

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis, After long research and debugging I understood that problem is in another place and tried to remove and install my nvidia drivers... That worked lol:)

Comment: oh, ok:) Nice to know that you found the cause.